# Is ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to thread safe in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

Say I have 2 DB connections, 1 to a mysql DB and another to a postgreSQL.
In my model, I want to be able to select from which DB to read (or write).
Something like:

```
def my_method
  ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(database: :non_default_db) do
    MyModel.where(...)
  end
end
```

Now, my question is, if another requests is executed at the same time for a different model, or even the same model but a different method, will AR use the default DB for those requests or will they use `:non_default_db` until that block is finished?

Thanks!